# How to use Arrays instead of NumberVector in Elki

Tags: elki

I want to use `preDistance(double[] v1, double[] v2, int start, int end)` function instead of `preDistance(NumberVector v1, NumberVector v2, int start, int end)`. How can i do this? is it possible through changing parser.vector-type or by changing dbc.parser?

Answer (score 0):

`double[]` are a pain if you want to allow subtyping, because you cannot subclass arrays. And in some cases, you will want to use only `float` precision to conserve memory. Thus, a wrapper is necessary.

You can use `DoubleVector.wrap()` in the latest version of ELKI. In many cases, the JVM should be able to optimize this well enough via escape analysis.

Comment: Understanding and changing someone else code is really a headache especially for newbies like me.

Comment: In particular code that covers a wide range of use cases (such as different precision vectors, sparse vectors, etc.) tends to get a bit more complicated, too. There just is no way to avoid this if you want to also allow, e.g., float precision. But if you use the APIs such as `NumberVector` as much as possible things are usually easier than if you try to use just a single class and make it work with double[].

Comment: When i am using relation variable it's containing all the data rows available in csv file in my csv file 45000 id's were there. Is it possible to divide data in relation variable into two parts i mean 22500 rows in one relation variable and 22500 in second relation variable?

Comment: The `ProxyDatabase` can be used to build a subset view on top of an existing relation. (On the relation level, the class is `ProxyView`) This is necessary for some algorithms that run other algorithms on data partitions.

Comment: Okay but i can't understand how i will divide a relation in two parts using ProxyView or ProxyDatabase?

Comment: Well, select the `DBIDs` that you want to have. There is no built-in function for a 50-50 split, because that is not frequently needed (also, you are not clear whether you want a random split, or not), but you can use, e.g., `ArrayDBIDs#slice`, to split an array of DBIDs.

Comment: Can you please give an example of using ArrayDBIDs to split an relation into half

Comment: Have you tried something like `ids.slice(0, ids.size()/2)`? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but in my case i need two Relation<O> objects with 50-50 ratio in them but with ArrayDBIDs it will be an int not a relation.

Comment: i am doing like this Relation<O> relation1 = (Relation<O>) ids.slice(0, ids.size() / 2); and it is giving runtime exception.

Comment: Yes, DBIDs are not relations. Don't do random casts. Use the proxy classes mentioned above to create a view onto a relation. The IDs specify which objects to view.

Comment: Can you please give an example

Comment: Sir i am waiting for your reply

Comment: I do not have time to prepare a complete example. Use the classes mentioned above.

Comment: Okay i see. Just tell i did this. is it right or wrong `DBIDs ids = relation.getDBIDs();
   ArrayDBIDs aids = (ArrayDBIDs) ids;
    aids.slice(0, ids.size()/2);

    ProxyView<O> pv = new ProxyView<>(ids, relation);`

Comment: Don't cast. Use `DBIDUtil.ensureArray` to make sure it is an array (and convert otherwise). But yes, that is likely what you should do.

Comment: i will try without casting too. Is it possible to combine result in two knnq objects into one knnq object?

Comment: You can't combine *query* objects. You probably meant to combine knnlist results? You'll likely have to do that yourself, as there is more than one way to "combine" them; so you need to be explicit.

Comment: i am talking about combining `KNNQuery<O> knnq` type of two objects.

Comment: because i used a foreach loop to give results from a list of callables `List<Callable<KNNQuery>>` and now after first iteration foreach is replacing value of first iteration in `knnq` instead of combining results of both iterations ` knnq = future.get();`.

Comment: I do not understand. It does not make sense to put a future around a KNNQuery. You will usually need only *one* query (and execute it multiple times).

Comment: what i did actually is divided query in two parts and run it on two different threads but now after running in two different parts when i get result of queries in ` for (Future<KNNQuery> future : executor.invokeAll(callables)){ KNNQery<O> knnq = future.get()` foreach loop is replacing result of first future in knnq with second future result and i am only getting second future result in knnq but i need result of both future's in knnq.

Comment: `KNNQuery` is not the *result*, but the prepared query. Think of a "prepared query" in SQL APIs. The result is a `KNNList`.

Comment: it means i divided a query into two queries and as a result i am having knnlist? if i am having knnlist as result than how can i join two knnlist's ?

Comment: There is no *uniquely* defined "join" operation on KNN lists. Everybody will understand something different here. So you will have to be *explicit* on what *exactly* you want to happen, and thus likely need to implement this yourself.